# Siri Shortcuts IntentsUI Extension Not Displaying for Any Failure Responses

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit

I have a project configured with IntentsUI and Intents extensions. In my intent handler, when I pass a *success* response (custom or otherwise) to the completion handler, my IntentViewController is properly displayed by Siri.

The same goes for the *ready* response.

However, a *failure* response of any kind will not display a custom UI; instead the default Siri UI is displayed and my custom IntentViewController is not being called in any way (I verified this w/ breakpoints).

I'm able to narrow down the cause to this "success/failure" response type by switching a custom response between *success* and *failure*; when it's marked as *success* in my .intentdefinition file, the custom UI displays correctly, and when it's marked as *failure*, it does not.

Seems like this might be intentional––the custom UI does appear in Spotlight––but I haven't been able to find anything in the docs that say this, and it seems to me like it should work in Siri.

EDIT: After failing to find any help online, I turned to Apple. Here's an example project I made to highlight the issue: https://github.com/philipshen/IntentsUIBug

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: @stepheaw I haven't found an authoritative answer, but just judging by how consistent the behavior is I think Siri will just not show a custom UI for failure responses (Spotlight will, however)

Comment: I'm frustrated because a lot as changed from iOS 12 -> iOS 13 especially with the new shortcuts app and how the shortcuts app has a pre-installed widget. My voice commands are automatically showing up there which is great, But some of my shortcuts don't work from there. Also, If you actually go into the new shortcuts app, you get totally different UI and behavior (my shortcuts work from here) What bothers me and how there little documentation, and to debug this siri extension and try new things is time consuming because of the intents definition and how it has to be wired up